# How to call a function defined in C# with same params,return type and same name but in different case from a VB.NET project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I have a class project a.dll which is compiled in C#. It contains the following code.

```
public class MyClass{
    public int Add(int i,int j)
    {
      return (i+j);
    }

    public int add(int i,int j)
    {
      return (i+j)*2;
    }
}
```

from a C# project I can call these functions like this

```
public class MyOtherClass{
 MyClass mcls=new MyClass();
 mcls.Add(1,2);
 mcls.add(2.3);
}
```

But how can I call this from a `VB.Net Project` ? I am not in a position to use Visual Studio right now. So its very helpful if someone will provide an answer.

**EDIT 1**

I am having a VB.NET project and I need to add the reference of a C# dll (`say dll contains MyClass`).So that I can call two methods (`Add(int,int) , add(int,int)`). But in VB.NET this is case sensitive. Is there any way to achieve this ?

**EDIT 2**

Suppose I  added reference to the dll and so I can able to call the functions.

```
Dim myObj as New MyClass
myObj.Add(1,2)
myObj.add(1,2)
```

If this code works how the compiler identify the correct function ?

Comment: Why not just rename add to AddAndDouble?

Comment: +1 good logic ! but violates CLS  guidelines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to use reflection here - VB simply cannot determine which function you are calling since in VB 'add' is identical to 'Add'.

Here's what I did to test it (I'm not really sure which 'BindingFlags' you need to combine here):

```
Dim mcls As New [MyClass]
Dim t As Type = mcls.GetType()
Dim x = t.InvokeMember("add", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, mcls, New Object() {1, 2})
Dim y = t.InvokeMember("Add", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, mcls, New Object() {1, 2})
```

Comment: I just simplified it somewhat - you don't need a separate assembly load - it's already loaded, so just use 'GetType'.

Comment: Thanks. its a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

if your C# code is CLS compliant, you can simply add a reference to it to your vb.net project.namespace , public members in the DLL  can be acessed

**More here** 
http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/290

**You can use free online convesion tools also .**
eg : http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

**update:**

Read this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/dda8d7cb-0fa1-43d6-a90f-6c4bed0b40bb

```
Dim c As New MyClass()
MsgBox(c.Add(1, 2)) 'if only Add() is Available
```

**update2:**
**As per above link Note:**

Also, in the C# project, add the following to `AssemblyInfo.cs:`

```
using System;

// etc

[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]
```

**update3:**

as i said above  you want **to ensure that you C# code is CLS compliant**.
***C# is case-sensitive,  where VB.NET  is not***. you are *violating*  **CLS  guidelines**

Please Note **update2** to ensure compliant nature

**At last i found the article that guided me long ago**

http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Making-Your-Code-CLS-Compliant/

**update4:**

**Another Scope** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163750.aspx

Comment: I added reference and how to call the function ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually VB will not let you call either `Add` method by name. You will get a compiler error indicating the name `Add` is ambiguous. Giving two public members names which differ only by case is not CLS-compliant. Call up the person who wrote the C# class and tell them to use CLS-compliant names. If they won't do that, then you will have to resort to reflection.

Comment: agreed your opinion. +1 :) This question is an interview question asked to my friend and he checked with me for a solution. Thanks

Comment: @VeeKayBee please let me know if I got the job :)

Comment: Sure. he is selected, but he don't any idea about the answer of his question